# Cartesian products as subsets of the power sets of the power sets of the union

Tags: set-theory

For nonempty sets $A_i$, where $i\in I$ are the index, is it always true $\prod_{i\in I}A_i\subset \mathcal{P}\left(\mathcal{P}\left(\cup_{i\in I}A_i\right)\right)$? When $I:=\{1,2\}$, the statement is true. That is, $A_1 \times A_2\subset  \mathcal{P}\left(\mathcal{P}\left(A_1\cup A_2\right)\right)$. I want to know if it's still true for more than two factor sets, but can't find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, $A_1 \times A_2 \neq \prod\limits_{i \in \{1, 2\}} A_i$ in most cases. The  The former is the set of all ordered pairs $(a_1, a_2)$ where each $a_i$ is in $A_i$, while the latter is the set of all functions $f : \{1, 2\} \to A_1 \cup A_2$ such that $f_i \in A_i$ for all $i$.

The specifics of your answer will depend on the exact definition of ordered pairs, but in general, the subset relation does not hold, as $I$ may possess elements of much higher rank than any $A_i$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the ordered-pairs definition and the mapping definition are not equivalent? Also, for example, for $(A_1\times A_2)\times A_3$, should I consider it as a subset of 
$$\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}\left((A_1\times A_2)\cup A_3\right)\subset\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}\left(\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}\left(A_1\cup A_2\right)\cup A_3\right)?$$
Or simply just $\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}\left(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\right)$? Thanks